dynamic components with turbo
I want to make the components dynamic through turbo so that when someone follows another person so it increments to his followers component, the problem is that this component is working but i must reload the page to see the result (incrementation in user's followership)
<p>Followers: 
<strong>
    <%= turbo_frame_tag "followers_count_#{user.id}" do %>
    <%= @user.followers.count %>
    <% end %>
</strong>
</p>
<p>Following: 
<strong>
    <%= turbo_frame_tag "following_count_#{current_user.id}" do %>
    <%= @user.following.count %>
    <% end %>
</strong>
</p>


Can you share your controller handling new follows? It should call one of broadcast_* methods with the "followers_count_#{user.id}" and "following_count_#{current_user.id}" target, to send those frames to the browsers. But since you did not share it – it's not even clear if you're doing it.

If you want to dynamically change the page user is currently seeing, there's multiple options.
Turbo 8 Morphing
As you are using Turbo, if it's Turbo 8 you can benefit from its morphing feature.
Nice article can be read here (and I recommend to read about the feature, for it to be understandable what's happening), but basically you can do something like (let's presume we are on UserController#show):

to your view, you add <%= turbo_stream_from @user %>

this makes the page "subscribe" for changes on @user object


in your Follower model, you have has_one :following and add touch: true

this makes user.updated_at change when new follower is added
maybe you implement this using other models/structures, so you have to find a way to do the same effect - change user.updated_at when new follower is added.



If you have ActionCable (Websockets) working, this should be all and you can see the content change.
Explicitely broadcast from controller
If you have websockets, but don't want to turn morphing on, you can simply broadcast from your FollowerController#create (or similar).
Poll for changes - refresh turbo-frame
You can make the turbo-frame filled remotely using turbo-frame src: user_followers_count_path(user_id:), and then you can, using some js, force this turbo-frame to "refresh" periodically (example here, you basically just remove the src and add it again, and turbo-frame will reload).
If you don't want to bother with morphing, websockets,.. (which can all get complicated), I would recommend this way.
